# Adb command to get versionCode from apk

Tags: android, adb, version, android-manifest

Is there an `adb` command to run on a `.apk` which gives me the `android:versionCode` that is set in the `AndroidManifest` file of that apk?

Basically, how do I get the version code of the `apk` using `adb`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For Version Name :

```
adb shell dumpsys package my.package | grep versionName
```

For Version Code :

```
adb shell dumpsys package my.package | grep versionCode
```

Also you can try this below too:

Android: Get `versionName` or `versionCode` of an APK from the command line
You can use aapt in android's build-tools directory of whatever build tools version you're using.

You pass that tool the badging command, and then pass it the location of your APK.

Example:

```
$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt dump badging app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk
```

If you scroll through all the output, you can find the `versionName` and `versionCode`.

Comment: This means that I can do it only after installing the apk on a device? Where is the .apk in this command?

Comment: adb command would only work for installed apk, if you want directly to get this data from apk flle, you should try unzipping it and then try to read AndroidManifest file using File operations.